# Encrypting $_GET variable in URL so user cannot access other profiles

Tags: php, encryption

I want to be able to email my clients a link to their profile. The link looks something like this;

https://www.example.com/admin-area/files/edit_tenant.php?tenant_id=37

I don't want the user to be able to change the '37' to '38' and edit another person's profile.

I'm thinking I need to encrypt the '37' in some way. I've done my research online but think I might be over thinking it as I've started coming across 'salts', etc.

I'm after a simple but secure solution using PHP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Obfuscating the URL parameter isn't what you should do. Authorize profile editing, keep an owner id in the database, and compare that prior editing/saving.

Comment: In addition to the above suggestions, using a UUID rather than an autoincrement id can make id values less predictable

Comment: If your users can log in, then you really implement some kind of authorization logic in your PHP code rather than relying on luck. If your system doesn't allow users to log in, then you should generate a random and long token and store that in the database. Then you can use that token as a replacement of the id.

Comment: I haven't got round to creating a login system yet so this is a temporary solution. I totally agree with you @mario but is there a relatively safe system for now?

Comment: For access purposes, I would not recommend using GET variables at all.  Look into using SESSION variables

Comment: @nomistic - How could I email the client a link to their profile using session variables?

Comment: you would use the token method as described below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a "token" field in your users table. When a user signs up in your system produce a random string (lets say 40 characters) and insert this token as well as other information. So when U want to look up for a user , Look for him/her with his token, instead of id. In this way no one can guess others token!

In order to generate random string you can use the function below:

```
function generateRandomString($length = 40) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[random_int(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
```

Note: `random_int()` is a PHP 7 function, but there is a [polyfill available for PHP 5](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat).

Comment: What method should I use to generate the token?

Comment: @MichaelLB use the code which Scott said or the function I added to the answer

Comment: There's been a recent surge in questions like this, so I wrote a post explaining it in detail: https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php

Comment: @ScottArciszewski - Your post has really helped me understand things, thanks a lot for writing it. I'm ready to implement your advice but when I call 'echo generateSelector();' it returns '+/ '. Can you help?

Comment: @ScottArciszewski - I have included your polyfill for PHP 5 using this code;

// this can be removed once the site is running on php 7
foreach (glob("../inc/php7/*.php") as $filename)
{
    require_once $filename;
}

Comment: You only need to include `lib/random.php`; it will intelligently load all of the rest of them.

Comment: @ScottArciszewski - I have changed the include but when I run; function generateSelector()
{
    return strtr(
        '+/',
        '-_',
        base64_encode(
            random_bytes(9)
        )
    );
}

echo generateSelector(); it returns just '+/'.

Comment: ... Wow, I got the arguments wrong. Sorry. The code has been fixed. https://3v4l.org/Zr6GH

Comment: @ScottArciszewski - Thanks. Why does it return '+/' before the output?

Comment: Instead of passing the random value to the first argument of strtr, I passed it to the third. Total amateur mistake that I really should have caught, sorry about that. The code as written now will work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89522/discussion-between-michael-lb-and-scott-arciszewski).

Answer (score 0):

Don't allowing to in(de)crement id it is the right way! You'd look at [this](https://philsturgeon.uk/http/2015/09/03/auto-incrementing-to-destruction/) page. Shortly: you dont have to use hashing/obfuscate functions. Instead you'd generate uniue random ids(for example UUIDs).

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Mario what this probably isn't the best idea ever, security wise... However if you absolutely have to be able to give users such access then you can use the php hash functions. Create a hash based off of the userID+Email/some other identifier and save that to the db... Then use that as your userID=

Info on hash functions :http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php

Comment: Thanks. To ensure the hash is unique should I use userID+current time and date?

Comment: The hash should be unique regardless, but it wouldn't hurt at all to use the current date time :)

Answer (score -2):

something you can do is:

1. When you are creating the email link, use the simple md5 function to encrypt the id.

`$token = md5($tenant_id); // i.e.output: a5bfc9e07964f8dddeb95fc584cd965d`

2. Save the "token" into the db for that user (you can add a column named token or something like that).
3. When the user goes to the profile with the tenant_id param (I'd use "token" o just "t" to give less info to possible attackers), look for that value in the db searching by the new column you added.

Done, and you don't need to know more about encrypting :)

Comment: No, that's terrible. Hash functions are deterministic. Please read this: https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded